# Error on plugin activation and creating new page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Trying to write an OOP plugin, migrating from a script monkey plugin.

I need to create a number of pages of plugin activation, and have the following code:

```
  public function __construct()
  {
    global $wpdb;
    $this->tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'arch_church_nominations';
    $this->activate();
  }

  public function activate()
  {
    $this->createTable();   // this works fine
    $this->createPages();
  }

  ...

  private function createPages()
  {
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php");

    $nominationPost = array(
      'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags('Nominations'),
      'post_content'  => 'Nominations parent',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $this->$parentId = wp_insert_post($nominationPost);   // <-- this line
  }
}

$archChurchNominations = new ArchChurchNominations();
```

The noted line above if included causes the following error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'feeds' of non-object in /Users/[USERNAME]/Projects/wordpress/wp-includes/post.php on line 4482
```

However the exact same code snippet works fine, if not in an OOP plugin. What's wrong with my config please?

Comment: Why are you enquiring wp-includes/pluggable.php?

Comment: You're using `wp_insert_post()` too early. The problem likely that is that you are running `$this->activate()` inside your class constructor, which means that it's probably running on every page load. How are you instantiating this class, and registering the activation hook?

Comment: hi @JacobPeattie yes I am.
I found an example on line that had `new ArchChurchNominations();` at the bottom of the file, rather than calling an init function. SHould I switch to an init function you think?

Comment: You need to use register_activation_hook if you want something to run only on activation.

Comment: ah ok! i thought it got rid of the need to register that hooks, thats simple enough cheers
Next question though, I need to keep a reference to the post id it creates for other stuff, obviously it needs to be a static function now so can't use $this - how do I do this?